# setup revmob phonegap android ?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, revmob

My application is set up with a menu, and 3 pages, no one looks at the menu for more than 3 seconds so it won't have time for the ad to even load, so I'd like to put the pop up when you open one of the 3 pages. I use phonegap and all 3 pages are webview, but in the readme that revmob includes, it has a html code attatched, where would I put this? How would I make it pop up when the page is opened. Please help, i'm using this. http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/phonegap_cordova.html I don't know to put the code in my html files or android app